Query very slow when sorting on 1:N datetime column
We have gotten a legacy code base where quite many joins from various tables and eventually a sort on a joined table date column is performed. This whole operation takes from 20s and 90s to complete, which is unacceptable. All tables have Ids as primary keys.
We use EF Core as our ORM, so the generated SQL may look a bit odd. The SQL Server is hosted on Azure.
What we have done so far was adding an index on the OrderNode.
Create NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_OrderNode_OrderIndex on [OrderNode] (Deleted, OrderIndex) Include (OrderId, Description, City, Zip, CountryCode, Reference, ShowDescription, IsFull)

and
CREATE INDEX IX_OrderNode_ArrivalPlan ON OrderNode (ArrivalPlan, IsMain) INCLUDE (ShowDescription, Description, CountryCode, Zip, City)

And one on the order, which was suggested by SSMS.
CREATE INDEX IX_Order_StausId ON [Order] (StatusId) INCLUDE (OrderId)

Please find the execution plan here:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1_WQ3xQA
Addition: The SQL DB has currently 100 DTUs, which are maxed out with this query. Running locally, the query takes about 400ms. Increasing the DTUs is out of the question.
The full query is:
SELECT [o].[Version], CASE
    WHEN [o5].[Id] IS NOT NULL OR [o].[DriverId] <> -1 OR [o].[DriverId] IS NULL THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
END, [t7].[ShortName], CASE
    WHEN [t9].[Id] IS NOT NULL THEN [t9].[ShortName]
    ELSE [t8].[ShortName]
END, [o].[ContainerLength], [t2].[ContainerTypeCode], [o].[ContainerNumber], [o].[ExportImportType], [t].[Reference], [t].[ArrivalPlan], [t4].[Text], CASE
    WHEN [t6].[Id] IS NOT NULL AND ([t6].[DriverId] <> -1 OR [t6].[DriverId] IS NULL) AND ([t10].[ContractId] IS NULL OR [t10].[AllowDriverDetails] = CAST(1 AS bit)) THEN [t6].[DriverId]
    ELSE NULL
END, CASE
    WHEN [t6].[Id] IS NOT NULL AND ([t6].[DriverId] <> -1 OR [t6].[DriverId] IS NULL) THEN CASE
        WHEN [t10].[ContractId] IS NULL OR [t10].[AllowDriverDetails] = CAST(1 AS bit) THEN COALESCE([t6].[FirstName], N'') + N' ' + COALESCE([t6].[LastName], N'') + N' (' + COALESCE([t6].[ShortName], N'') + N')'
        ELSE N'Assigned'
    END
    ELSE NULL
END, [o].[OrderId], [o].[StatusId], [o].[Info], [o3].[AssignedTo], CASE
    WHEN [o3].[AssignedTo] = 1 THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
END, CASE
    WHEN [t9].[Id] IS NOT NULL THEN [t9].[CompanyId]
    ELSE [t8].[CompanyId]
END, (
    SELECT TOP(1) [o6].[LicensePlateTruck]
    FROM [OrderNode] AS [o6]
    WHERE [o6].[Deleted] = CAST(0 AS bit) AND [o].[OrderId] = [o6].[OrderId] AND [o6].[LicensePlateTruck] IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY [o6].[OrderIndex] DESC), (
    SELECT TOP(1) [o7].[LicensePlateTrailer]
    FROM [OrderNode] AS [o7]
    WHERE [o7].[Deleted] = CAST(0 AS bit) AND [o].[OrderId] = [o7].[OrderId] AND [o7].[LicensePlateTrailer] IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY [o7].[OrderIndex] DESC), [o].[ContainerTara], [o].[ContainerContentWeight], [o].[ContainerWeight], [o].[CustomsInfo], [o].[IsContentDanger], [o].[PlannedStart], [o].[PlannedEnd], [o].[TruckAppId], CAST([o].[ContainerTypeId] AS int), [o].[CustomerContactName], [o].[CustomerContactPhone], [o].[CustomerContactEmail], [o].[CustomerOperatorRef], [o].[ContainerContent], [o].[ContainerContentCountry], [o].[CustomsNumber], [o].[MaerskWorkingOrder], [o].[SealType], [o].[SealNumber], CASE
    WHEN [o].[ExportImportType] = 'E' AND [t0].[IsFull] = CAST(0 AS bit) THEN [t0].[Reference]
    ELSE NULL
END, (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [OrderNode] AS [o8]
    WHERE [o8].[Deleted] = CAST(0 AS bit) AND [o].[OrderId] = [o8].[OrderId]), CAST([o].[StatusId] AS int), [t3].[ShortName], CASE
    WHEN [t6].[Id] IS NOT NULL AND ([t6].[DriverId] <> -1 OR [t6].[DriverId] IS NULL) AND ([t10].[ContractId] IS NULL OR [t10].[AllowDriverDetails] = CAST(1 AS bit)) THEN [t6].[ShortName]
    ELSE NULL
END, [o].[CustomerOrderRef], CASE
    WHEN [t0].[ShowDescription] = CAST(1 AS bit) THEN [t0].[Description]
    ELSE COALESCE([t0].[CountryCode], N'') + N' ' + COALESCE([t0].[Zip], N'') + N' ' + COALESCE([t0].[City], N'')
END, CASE
    WHEN [t].[ShowDescription] = CAST(1 AS bit) THEN [t].[Description]
    ELSE [t].[Name1]
END, CASE
    WHEN [t].[ShowDescription] = CAST(1 AS bit) THEN [t].[Description]
    ELSE COALESCE([t].[CountryCode], N'') + N' ' + COALESCE([t].[Zip], N'') + N' ' + COALESCE([t].[City], N'')
END, CASE
    WHEN [t1].[ShowDescription] = CAST(1 AS bit) THEN [t1].[Description]
    ELSE COALESCE([t1].[CountryCode], N'') + N' ' + COALESCE([t1].[Zip], N'') + N' ' + COALESCE([t1].[City], N'')
END
FROM [Order] AS [o]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [o0].[ArrivalPlan], [o0].[City], [o0].[CountryCode], [o0].[IsMain], [o0].[Description], [o0].[Name1], [o0].[Zip], [o0].[OrderId], [o0].[Reference], [o0].[ShowDescription]
    FROM [OrderNode] AS [o0]
    WHERE [o0].[Deleted] = CAST(0 AS bit)
) AS [t] ON [o].[OrderId] = [t].[OrderId] AND [t].[IsMain] = CAST(1 AS bit)
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [o1].[City], [o1].[CountryCode], [o1].[IsFull], [o1].[Description], [o1].[Zip], [o1].[OrderId], [o1].[OrderIndex], [o1].[Reference], [o1].[ShowDescription]
    FROM [OrderNode] AS [o1]
    WHERE [o1].[Deleted] = CAST(0 AS bit)
) AS [t0] ON [o].[OrderId] = [t0].[OrderId]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [o2].[City], [o2].[CountryCode], [o2].[IsLast], [o2].[Description], [o2].[Zip], [o2].[OrderId], [o2].[ShowDescription]
    FROM [OrderNode] AS [o2]
    WHERE [o2].[Deleted] = CAST(0 AS bit)
) AS [t1] ON [o].[OrderId] = [t1].[OrderId] AND [t1].[IsLast] = CAST(1 AS bit)
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [c].[ContainerTypeId], [c].[ContainerTypeCode]
    FROM [ContainerType] AS [c]
    WHERE [c].[Deleted] = CAST(0 AS bit)
) AS [t2] ON [o].[ContainerTypeId] = [t2].[ContainerTypeId]
INNER JOIN [OrderContract] AS [o3] ON [o].[OrderId] = [o3].[OrderId] AND 1 = [o3].[OrderIndex]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [c0].[CompanyId], [c0].[ShortName]
    FROM [Company] AS [c0]
    WHERE [c0].[Deleted] = CAST(0 AS bit)
) AS [t3] ON [o3].[AssignedTo] = [t3].[CompanyId]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [t5].[LanguageId], [t5].[Tag], [t5].[Text]
    FROM [Translation] AS [t5]
    WHERE [t5].[Deleted] = CAST(0 AS bit)
) AS [t4] ON N'tag_status' + CAST([o].[StatusId] AS nvarchar(100)) = [t4].[Tag] AND 1 = [t4].[LanguageId]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [d].[Id], [d].[DriverId], [d].[FirstName], [d].[LastName], [d].[ShortName]
    FROM [Driver] AS [d]
    WHERE [d].[Deleted] = CAST(0 AS bit)
) AS [t6] ON [o].[DriverId] = [t6].[DriverId]
LEFT JOIN [OrderContract] AS [o4] ON [o].[OrderId] = [o4].[OrderId] AND 1 = [o4].[StatusId] AND 1 = [o4].[AssignedTo]
LEFT JOIN [OrderContract] AS [o5] ON [o].[OrderId] = [o5].[OrderId] AND 1 = [o5].[StatusId] AND 1 = [o5].[AssignedFrom]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [c1].[CompanyId], [c1].[ShortName]
    FROM [Company] AS [c1]
    WHERE [c1].[Deleted] = CAST(0 AS bit)
) AS [t7] ON [o4].[AssignedFrom] = [t7].[CompanyId]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [c2].[CompanyId], [c2].[ShortName]
    FROM [Company] AS [c2]
    WHERE [c2].[Deleted] = CAST(0 AS bit)
) AS [t8] ON [o4].[AssignedTo] = [t8].[CompanyId]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [c3].[Id], [c3].[CompanyId], [c3].[ShortName]
    FROM [Company] AS [c3]
    WHERE [c3].[Deleted] = CAST(0 AS bit)
) AS [t9] ON [o5].[AssignedTo] = [t9].[CompanyId]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [c4].[ContractId], [c4].[AllowDriverDetails], [c4].[CustomerId], [c4].[Status], [c4].[SupplierId]
    FROM [CustomerSupplierRelation] AS [c4]
    WHERE [c4].[Type] = CAST(1 AS tinyint)
) AS [t10] ON [o5].[AssignedFrom] = [t10].[CustomerId] AND [o5].[AssignedTo] = [t10].[SupplierId] AND CAST(2 AS tinyint) = [t10].[Status]
WHERE [o].[Deleted] = CAST(0 AS bit) AND [t0].[OrderIndex] = 1 AND CAST([o].[StatusId] AS int) = 2150
ORDER BY [t].[ArrivalPlan] DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY


This is a heavy query that joins 18 table instances, that is suitable for batch processing. What's wrong with 90 seconds? I would assume this is not intended for online use to present data, is it?

Your INDEX on Order only contains two columns, but you are SELECTing far more than that; that index is unlikely to be helpful, unless that recommendation was for a subquery that's not in the snippet of the query we can see.

@TheImpaler Unfortunately, this is the main query, which is heavily used for displaying data in a table.

This query looks pretty good (for EF). I think you need an index on OrderNode (Deleted, OrderId) to handle the joins. But not sure it will help, how many orders are deleted vs not?

Combining the 3 times you have an INNER JOIN to a sub-query using SELECT ... FROM OrderNode into 1 sub-query might help. Especially when you alo take into account the SELECT TOP(1) [o6].[LicensePlateTruck] FROM [OrderNode] AS [o6] and the other sub-query on OrderNode.

There are 8k deleted orders versus ~300k non deleted ones.

Tbh, i wonder if your azure settings are underpowered, you have way too little rows for any kind of query to be an issue on a real server. But perhaps your clustered unique indexes are not on OrderID? In that case, that's the issue

We actually have 100 DTUs assigned, which costs about 250€/month. The next step is double the DTUs and the costs, which is not an option.
